# Card Counting Function

Tags: javascript

```
var count = 0;
function cc(card) {
  if (card <= 6){
    count++;
  }
  else if (card >= 10){
    count--;
  }
  else {
    count += 0;
  } 
  return count;
}

cc(2); 
cc("K"); 
cc(7); 
cc('K'); 
cc('A');
```

Writing a card counting function in JavaScript.  If `count <= 0` is should return `count + " Hold"`. If `count > 0` it should return `count + " Bet"`.  My issue is where do place the return so the function prints these outputs without returning and exiting the function.

Comment: It depends on where you want them returning you can simply `console.log(cc(22));` to see the output or set it to a variable `var x = cc(22)` and the `console.log(x)` this will print it to your console output do you want it to write it to a page on insert it somewhere on your page?

Comment: `return count + (count <= 0 ? " Hold" : " Bet");`

Comment: Assuming that the example code is a sample and not the actual code and that your writing an app for a browser, you output them to the log as suggested but you could use more of an AJAX approach and modify the DOM elements in question. Either way this function will eventually exit.

Answer (score 4):

You're nearly there. You simply need to add in the return statements in an `if...else...` at the end of the function so it will display the result after all the cards have been counted. Also for the cards to be counted correctly(blackjack rules), you have to change the `else...if...` condition to `else if (card <= 9)` for **String("K")** to be counted as **-1**, like so:

```
var count = 0;

function cc(card) {
if (card <= 6) {
  count++;
} else if (card <= 9) {
  count += 0;
} else {
  count--;
}
if (count <= 0){
  return count + " Hold"; /* Return here */
} else {
  return count + " Bet";  /* and here */
}

}

cc(2); cc(3); cc(7); cc('K'); cc('A');
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you explain how your answer addresses the problem(s) from the question? Code-only answers are not very useful, especially for further readers that stumble upon this post. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Create another if statement like this to return the count you want:

```
if (count <= 0) {
    console.log(count + " Hold");
    //or window.alert("Same text here");
}
else {
    console.log(return count + " Bet");
    //or window.alert("Same text here");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can place the returns inside the if statements such as:

```
if (card <=6) {
count++;
return count + " Bet";
} 
else if (card >= 10) {
count--;
return count + " Hold;
}
```

I'm still only learning, but I encountered this problem in FCC and this is how i solved it.

Answer (score 0):

use the `switch`

```
var count = 0;

function cc(card) {
  // Only change code below this line

  switch (card) {
    case 2:
    case 3:
    case 4:
    case 5:
    case 6:
      count++;
      break;
    case 10:
    case "J":
    case "Q":
    case "K":
    case "A":
      count--;
      break;
  }

  if (count > 0) {
    return count + " Bet";
  } else {
    return count + " Hold";
  }
  //return "Change Me";
  // Only change code above this line
}

// Add/remove calls to test your function.
// Note: Only the last will display
cc(2); cc(3); cc(7); cc('K'); cc('A');
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just add the 0 case:

```
var count = 0;

function cc(card) {
// Only change code below this line


switch (card){
case 2:
case 3:
case 4:
case 5:
case 6:
  count++;
  break;
case 7:
case 8:
case 9:
  count += 0;
  break;
case 10:
case "J":
case "Q":
case "K":
case "A":
  count--;
  break;
}
if (count > 0){
return count + " Bet";
}else if (count<=0) {
return count + " Hold";
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer:

```
LowValueCards = [2,3,4,5,6];
NoValueCards = [7,8,9];
HighValueCards = [10,"J","Q","K","A"];

if (LowValueCards.includes(card)) 
{
   count += 1;
} 
else if (NoValueCards.includes(card)) 
{
   count += 0;
}
else if (HighValueCards.includes(card))
{
   count -=1;
} 

return count + (count > 0 ? " Bet" : " Hold");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it on FCC.

```
    var count = 0;

    function cc(card) {       

    // Only change code below this line

   switch (card){
     case 2:
     case 3:
     case 4:
     case 5:
     case 6:
       count++;       
       break;       

     case 7:
     case 8:
     case 9:
       count = count;       
       break;

     case 10:
     case "J":
     case "Q":
     case "K":
     case "A":
       count--;       
       break;
   }

  if (count>0){
    return count + " Bet";
  }
  else return count + " Hold";
  // Only change code above this line
}

// Add/remove calls to test your function.
// Note: Only the last will display
cc(2); cc("J"); cc(9); cc(2); cc(7);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var count = 0;

  
function cc(card) {
  // Only change code below this line
  switch(card){
    
    case 2:
    case 3:
    case 4:
    case 5:
    case 6:
      count++;
      break;
      
    case 7:
    case 8:
    case 9:
      break;
      
    case 10:
    case 'J':
    case 'Q':
    case 'K':
    case 'A':
      count--;
      break;
      
  }
  
  
  return  count>0?count + " Bet":count + " Hold";
  // Only change code above this line
}

// Add/remove calls to test your function.
// Note: Only the last will display
cc(2); cc(3); cc(7); cc('K'); cc('A');
```

```js
var count = 0;

  
function cc(card) {
  // Only change code below this line
  switch(card){
    
    case 2:
    case 3:
    case 4:
    case 5:
    case 6:
      count++;
      break;
      
    case 7:
    case 8:
    case 9:
      break;
      
    case 10:
    case 'J':
    case 'Q':
    case 'K':
    case 'A':
      count--;
      break;
      
  }
  
  
  return  count>0?count + " Bet":count + " Hold";
  // Only change code above this line
}

// Add/remove calls to test your function.
// Note: Only the last will display
cc(2); cc(3); cc(7); cc('K'); cc('A');
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

This is my solution, you can use the ternary operator in the return:)

```js
var count = 0;

  
function cc(card) {
  // Only change code below this line
  switch(card){
    
    case 2:
    case 3:
    case 4:
    case 5:
    case 6:
      count++;
      break;
      
    case 7:
    case 8:
    case 9:
      break;
      
    case 10:
    case 'J':
    case 'Q':
    case 'K':
    case 'A':
      count--;
      break;
      
  }
  
  
  return  count>0?count + " Bet":count + " Hold";
  // Only change code above this line
}

// Add/remove calls to test your function.
// Note: Only the last will display
cc(2); cc(3); cc(7); cc('K'); cc('A');
```

Comment: duplicate and copied.

Answer (score -1):

```js
var count = 0;

  
function cc(card) {
  // Only change code below this line
  switch(card){
    
    case 2:
    case 3:
    case 4:
    case 5:
    case 6:
      count++;
      break;
      
    case 7:
    case 8:
    case 9:
      break;
      
    case 10:
    case 'J':
    case 'Q':
    case 'K':
    case 'A':
      count--;
      break;
      
  }
  
  
  return  count>0?count + " Bet":count + " Hold";
  // Only change code above this line
}

// Add/remove calls to test your function.
// Note: Only the last will display
cc(2); cc(3); cc(7); cc('K'); cc('A');
```